# Java with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am getting following exception when I tried to fetch the data from a mongodb collection. This collection is having very huge data.

The exception is:

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 10334 and error message 'BSONObj size: 24020168 (0x16E84C8) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)' on server 10.15.0.227:27017
```

And following is my query which I used to get the data from mongodb:

```
db.getCollection('triggered_policies').aggregate(
[{ "$match" : { "policy_name" : "EIQSOC-1040-ec"}}, 
{ "$project" : { "cust_created_at" : { "$add" : [ "$created_at" , 19800000]} , "event_ids" : "$event_ids" , "trigger_time" : "$trigger_time" , "created_at" : "$created_at" , "triggered_rules" : "$triggered_rules"}},
{ "$sort" : { "created_at" : -1}},
{ "$group" : 
    { "_id" : 
        { 
            "$hour" : "$cust_created_at"} , 
            "triggered_policies" : { "$addToSet" : { "trigger_time" : "$trigger_time" , "created_at" : "$created_at" , "event_ids" : "$event_ids" , "triggered_rules" : "$triggered_rules"}
        }
    }
}, 
{ "$sort" : { "_id" : 1}}
])
```

Following is the exact exception which we are getting:

```
Error: getMore command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "BSONObj size: 25994482 (0x18CA4F2) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)",
    "code" : 10334
}
```

Please help us to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the document created during aggregation exceeds the 16MB size restriction in mongo db. You might have to change your aggregate query to not accumulate too much data into a single document which exceeds the 16MB size limit.

Below is the quote from Mongo DB documentation:

*BSON Document Size
The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.
The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB provides the GridFS API. See mongofiles and the documentation for your driver for more information about GridFS.*

Comment: Defining an index on the created_at should help reducing the size of data manipulated during the aggregation.

Comment: Thank you JayKrish for your quick reply.

But help me to prepare that kind of query.

Comment: The issue is because of the $group, you are using $addToSet, which will add all unique data to an array and increase the document size. Instead, try to get only the required value from these documents.

Comment: Then do a horizontal accumulation, instead of vertically accumulating in the same document. i.e. change the query such that the output of aggregate query is multiple documents instead of one single document with all embedded data